# Defining a "norm" on a nice $*$-algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, algebras

Let $\mathbf{A}=(A,\odot,\mathbf{1}_A, ^*)$ be a (not necessarily associative) unital $*$-algebra over a real closed field $(K,\preceq)$. I shall say that $\mathbf{A}$ is $\textit{nicely normed}$ provided

$$\mathbf{a}+\mathbf{a}^{*} \in K[\mathbf{1}_A]$$

for all $\mathbf{a} \in A$, and additionally $\mathbf{a}\odot\mathbf{a}^{*} \succ \mathbf{0}_A$ for all nonzero $\mathbf{a}$. Here $K[\mathbf{1}_A]$ denotes the $K$-subalgebra generated by $\mathbf{1}_A$, naturally inheriting the ordered field structure from $K$.

Does the map $\mathbf{a} \mapsto \sqrt{\mathbf{a}\odot \mathbf{a}^{*}}$ define a submultiplicative "norm" $\| \cdot \|:\mathbf{A} \to K[\mathbf{1}_A] \cong K$? If not, what are the minimal constraints on $\mathbf{A}$ and $K$ for it to be so?

One can easily see that $\| \lambda \cdot \mathbf{a}\|=|\lambda| \cdot \| \mathbf{a} \|$, and $\| \cdot \|$ is clearly non-degenerate, so my main focus is getting subadditivity (i.e. the triangle inequality) and submultiplicativity to hold.

$\textbf{Edit}$: It may be useful to note that the map $(\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b}) \mapsto \frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{a}\odot \mathbf{b}^{*} + \mathbf{b} \odot \mathbf{a}^{*})$ defines a non-degenerate symmetric $K$-bilinear form, and hence that $\mathbf{a} \mapsto \mathbf{a}\odot \mathbf{a}^{*}$ defines an anisotropic quadratic form over $K$.

Comment: Do you have any examples where these assumptions don't just force $A$ to be either $K$ itself, the complex numbers $K[i]$ over $K$, or the quaternions $K[i, j, k]$ over $K$? I think I can prove these are the only finite-dimensional possibilities, and it's easy to check the norm property for each.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Sadly I do not. For a multiplicative norm, I do believe rather strongly that those would be the only possibilities. Although given that what I have here sort of resembles a composition algebra, and is seen to have multiplicative inverses given by $\mathbf{a}^{-1}=\frac{\mathbf{a}^{*}}{\mathbf{a} \odot \mathbf{a}^{*}}$, an analogue of Hurwitz's theorem may be applicable here.

Answer (score 1):

These assumptions imply that

$$\langle a, b \rangle = \frac{a^{\ast} b + b^{\ast} a}{2} \in K$$

defines a $K$-bilinear inner product on $A$ with values in $K$, so $\sqrt{ \langle a, a \rangle } = \sqrt{ a^{\ast} a }$ is a Euclidean / Hilbert space norm (and so in particular satisfies the triangle inequality). There is no need to assume that $K$ is rigid. Also the first assumption implies the second so the second assumption is redundant.

Moreover the norm is straightforwardly multiplicative. We have

$$(ab)^{\ast} ab = b^{\ast} a^{\ast} ab = a^{\ast} a b^{\ast} b$$

because by assumption $a^{\ast} a \in K$ is a scalar and so is central, hence can be commuted past $b^{\ast}$.

Comment: Sorry, which assumption is redundant? That $\mathbf{a}\odot\mathbf{a}^{*} \succ \mathbf{0}_A$? Moreover, $K$ may have a non-trivial self-inverse automorphism, which can screw with the bilinearity of the inner product. As for showing multiplicativity, aren't you implicitly assuming associativity?

Comment: @Quantum: the assumption that $a^{\ast} a = a a^{\ast} \in K$ follows from the assumption that $a + a^{\ast} \in K$, although yes, I am assuming associativity, for me algebras are associative by default. I have no idea why you need to assume rigidity to get that the inner product is bilinear; are you not assuming that the $\ast$-operation is $K$-linear? Can you write out what your actual definitions are in more detail in the OP then?

Comment: @Qioachu Ah I see, my bad. I should've made that clearer in my question. No, I was assuming that the conjugation is $K$-antilinear, but I suppose if we're working over fields with the same first order properties as $\mathbb{R}$, there's no harm in having * be $K$-linear.

Comment: @Quantum: what does "antilinear" mean if $K$ is a real closed field?

Comment: Are you implying that there are no (non-trivial) involutions on a real closed field?

Comment: @Quantum: for me "antilinear" implies that you've specified an involution on $K$ in advance. If all you're given is that $K$ is a real closed field then no involution has been specified. Again, all of this really should have been detailed in the OP. Moreover there are, in fact, no nontrivial involutions on a real closed field: the existence of such a thing is ruled out by the Artin-Schreier theorem (it would imply that the algebraic closure of the fixed field of the involution has degree $4$ but Artin-Schreier says the only possible degree is $1$ or $2$).